# How to show part of the repeated chart in altair

Tags: python, visualization, repeat, altair

i have used repeat in altair and the Result looks like this.

[image]

i was wondering how can i only show the Lower part that i have marked with a Red triangle.

the code that i have used:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import altair as alt

data_wine = datasets.load_wine (as_frame = True).frame
features = data_wine.columns.values[data_wine.columns.values != 'target']
    
alt.Chart(data_wine).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X(alt.repeat("column"), type = 'quantitative', scale = alt.Scale (nice = True)),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat("row"), type = 'quantitative', scale = alt.Scale (nice = True)),
    color = 'target:N'
).properties(
    width=150,
    height=150
).repeat(
    row = features,
    column = features
)#.interactive()
```

Comment: It seems that altair can't do it by itself. The reason is confirmed [here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2321): altair's maintainer @joelostblom has developed a wrapper package. See [this](https://joelostblom.github.io/altair_ally/examples.html). I've actually installed it and experimented with [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pnxiR-DpCgpFNc02xJXI47dl6R0T3Zzz?usp=sharing). Please check if the content is what you need.

Comment: You can check this link and disable it if you don't want to.

Comment: could you add you comment as an Answer @r-beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that altair can't do it by itself. The reason is confirmed https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2321: There is an experimental wrapper package with a more terse syntax for common exploratory plots that you could try out. See https://joelostblom.github.io/altair_ally/examples.html.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import altair as alt
import altair_ally as aly

data_wine = datasets.load_wine (as_frame = True).frame
features = data_wine.columns.values[data_wine.columns.values != 'target']
data_wine['target'] = data_wine['target'].astype(str)

aly.pair(data_wine,'target')
```

[image]

Comment: @joelostblom I was looking for a solution to this problem as well and was able to find and introduce your great package. I hope you will incorporate it into altair.

Comment: Thank you, it is exciting to see someone else using `altair_ally` =) It is still experimental so please open issues if you see something that is not working as it should or just to leave general feedback on your experience! I made small edit to your answer to clarify that I am not the maintainer of Altair, I just help out a bit, like here on SO.

Comment: @joelostblom I thought it was a maintainer since it is often commented on Github. Thank you for correcting my comment.